# Taylor diagram using JJAS mean values in R

Tags: r

I need some assistance in solving the following issue;

I am drawing a Taylor diagram using R. I calculated the JJAS mean precipitation values (mm/day) for observation and two models than I manually defined those values to get the Taylor diagram. It gives me output but that does not seem right as standard deviation values are too low (sample is attached).

This is the code I am using:

```
library(plotrix)
ref<-c(3.3592,4.1377,4.0888,3.3098)
model1<-c(2.5053,3.0912,2.9271,2.4238)
model2<-c(2.2181,2.7910,2.7024,2.2495)
taylor.diagram(ref,model1,add=FALSE,col="red")
taylor.diagram(ref,model2,add=TRUE,col="blue")
```

Alternate way is to use netcdf files of observation and models but I don't know how to extract the precipitation information and use them (I know how to view netcdf data in R but extraction is challenging at this stage for me).

Kindly solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about this but a cursory look at the code of `taylor.diagram` clarifies what is going on here.
If you enter `taylor.diagram` without parentheses in the console it will print the function. Around line 15 you will find this function to calculate SD:

```
SD <- function(x, subn) {
    meanx <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    devx <- x - meanx
    ssd <- sqrt(sum(devx * devx, na.rm = TRUE)/(length(x[!is.na(x)]) - 
        subn))
    return(ssd)
}
```

We can run this function with parameter `subn` as `TRUE` or `FALSE` (in R, `TRUE` equates to 1 and `FALSE` equates to 0):

```
> SD(ref, TRUE)
[1] 0.4505061
> SD(ref, FALSE)
[1] 0.3901498
> SD(model1, FALSE)
[1] 0.2798994
> SD(model1, TRUE)
[1] 0.3232
```

And from this we can see that `subn` is set to `FALSE`. Further inspection of the code shows:

```
subn <- sd.method != "sample"
```

In other words: if `sd.method` equals `sample` (the default value) then `subn` will be `FALSE`.
It's up to you to decide what is the correct choice here.

One of the great things of R is that all R functions can be inspected at the console. Doing so can resolve most questions related to 'why is this function behaving like this' with limited effort.

Comment: Dear Paul,Thank you for replying back. Let me dig in to my script further following your kind advice. I hope to get better results this time :)